# Why don't I have a iPhone monotouch project option in monodevelop after installing monotouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I just installed the following on my macbook pro running Mac OS X 10.6.6:

1. xcode_4.0.2_and_ios_sdk_4.3
2. MonoFramework-2.10.1_3.macos10.novell.x86
3. MonoDevelop-20402005

in that order as described by http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Installation.

However, when I start monodevelop, I am not seeing a iPhone Monotouch Project option under the C# projects. I don't get any error messages when monodevelop starts up.

Is there a way to troubleshoot this? Anyone have any suggestions on what else I can try to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

You know I feel very stupid, Dimitris thank you i didn't realize that was a seperate download on the site for some reason i thought installing monodevelop would take care of it all. Installing monotouch (what do you know... ) did the trick